# VSTF - Can't see newly created remote branches

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

Using Visual Studio 2017 V 15.8.5. I created some branches on a project from home as a different user and pushed them to repo. The branches show up in the web view in Azure Dev Ops. No matter what I try I cannot get my local Visual Studio at work to see the new remote branches.

I have tried checking out master and fetching, syncing, restarting Visual Studio and what seems like all the "normal" fixes for this. There are a lot of sites out there that say it is a confusing issue but to :

1) Check out master

2) Fetch -or- sync -or- pull

Nothing seems to work.

*EDIT* - Looks like a duplicate post but the typical answer isn't working.

Comment: Are you on a fork at work? Check the output of ```git remote -v``` to make sure your ```origin``` is same for both home and work clones.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the simplest things...I feel so stupid.

You have to expand "remotes/origin". I was looking at local branches. The remotes don't show locally until you double click on them in "remotes/origin"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Where I was going wrong. When you create a repository you need to get the URL of the repository - it does not auto fill. If you are using Azure then you go to

> Repos -> files -> Clone

and get the URL for the project. Copy that and then paste that into the text box for the URL of the repo.

Not sure why this doesn't auto populate considering you just created the repo using the same set of tools...must be more complicated than that.